# Code formatting is too unfriendly to mobile

Tags: discussion, support, mobile-web

On mobile there's no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> shortcut or mouse navigation available, and when I write

```
<pre><code>
some code code code
Manually escaped &amp; ,&lt; and &gt;
# These are the only things required to be escaped in HTML
</code></pre>
```

$tack Overflow tells me

> You post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code.

**But** the [confusing center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) says:

> Indent four spaces to create an escaped `<pre> <code>` block.

So what? It means 4-space indention is **equivalent to** `<pre> <code>`. This **is** code if I use `<pre>` (and `<code>`) tag!

```
code();
It looks simple & simple to use <pre> tag 
Even if it doesn't look good in edit mode.
Indention gives me no way to bold or italic my code.
But who cares about edit mode?
Who edits codes?
```

It's a great job to add 4 spaces before each line in my code when it's tens of lines long, so I'd prefer to change `&<>`s into HTML escape sequences, which will not pass the test. Can this be more friendly to mobile? I don't want to repeatedly hit space and navigating through lines when a physical keyboard isn't available.

**Edit**: My question is "Using indention is mandatory for code, which makes it unfriendly for mobile". Why can't I use `<pre><code>` tag?

Comment: If that's the cause for that warning that's especially annoying because of the [weird equivalence](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348465/code-formatting-article-in-help-center-is-confusing) the help center article tries to draw between `<pre><code>` and the normal format button.

Comment: @JasonC I gave up trying to understand the [confusing center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). It's too "good" to make me think `pre-code`tags are capable of replacing indention.